# Do slotted screws indicate old fixtures? How old?

Tags: light-fixture, screws

I have been doing renovations in my apartment, which is in a building that is at least 120 years old.

I have noticed that many of the fixtures I remove are installed with slotted screws. I don't see new fixtures sold with slotted screws anymore, and I was wondering if the slotted screws give any indication of the age of the old fixtures.

Was there a point in time when Phillips and combo screws took over?

[image: You probably know what a slotted screw looks like]

Comment: (Screw provided to give scale to praying mantis.) :) Very nice pic! Note that there's nothing inherently wrong with an older fixture or with a slotted screw. You'll notice that every one of your face plates is held on with slotted screws... (except, perhaps, for the fancier "screwless" ones which have a clip that's screwed on then a cover that clips to it. I don't have any of those high-falutin' ones, so I'm not sure)

Comment: Well, the older fixtures are generally ugly as sin, but they certainly work -- it takes a lot to kill a light bulb socket. I don't love the slotted screws, though. They're fine in a face plate, but if they are used anywhere that is awkward to reach, they can really make the process of getting them out gratuitously difficult.

Comment: Won't disagree with you on the pain of driving/removing slotted screws, just that there's nothing inherently _wrong_ with an old device that works. ;) If need be, go buy a few packages of newer screws and replace 'em as you go!

Comment: Having recently sorted through some bridge size bolts, I am now terrified of that praying mantis.  I would be more at ease if it was obviously domesticated, i.e. had a saddle and reins.

Comment: It's about 4 inches long and pretty friendly. As long as you're not a cricket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say by around 1990 most fixtures and devices (outlets, switches) had been shipped with combination screws (both #2 Phillips and slotted drivers work, or sometimes #2 square and slotted). The transition probably started in the mid-70s and varied by region of manufacture, backstock quantities, etc.

*<sub>Answer informed by vague accumulated memory, not empirical data.</sub>*

Comment: I'll take vague memory, thanks! I don't expect to get a precise answer here, I'm just curious to roughly date things.